# bash scripting to update an XML element attribute based on prior value

Tags: xml, bash

I have an xml file that consists of strings

```
<server name="srv-usr--crt-Internal.vcdn--lfagent1">
```

and

```
<server name="srv-usr--crt-Internal.vcdn--lfagent2">
                                          ^^^^^^^^
```

I want to run a bash script, which continuously executes the xml file by changing the value in the server name i.e for the first time the values will be `lfagent1` and `lfagent2`, the xml file is executed and then the value changes to `lfagent3` and `lfagent4`. There should be around 500 to 1000 such iterations.

How to write a bash script for this test?

Comment: What do you mean by 'executing an xml file'?

Comment: It would be helpful if we knew how to separately address the two `server` entries within the file -- if there's a different XPath path to each.

Comment: What's the point of changing it continuously? Why not change it to the final result after all the iterations?

Comment: @Barmar, ...I'm presuming that some other piece of test code is being run between each iteration.

Comment: An option might be to copy/paste the original file into as many  clones as needed, replacing the lfagent string underway, finally cat-ting the files and 'executing' (whatever the meaning) the result.

Comment: collapsar, pardon? What does cat have to do with anything? And doing the replacement in a safe and sane (read: XML-aware) way is the hard part of the problem; one can't simply hand-wave over it.

Comment: Yes, there is another test code that is running in between these iterations. it works in the following manner: Each time I modify the xml file, a new configuration is being pushed to all the servers, and all the previous historic data gets discarded. I wanted to do a testing to see how the servers perform when there is a continuous push of new configuration. Instead of changing the name manually, I thought that a bash script would be useful and much more helpful in determining the performance

Comment: By the way -- if the document is inside an XML namespace (that is, if any parent element had `xmlns='...'` specified), many answers here will need to change to remain accurate. Thus, the question as given may not be complete enough for answers to be tested/guaranteed.

Comment: Are there other `<server>` elements with different names that _shouldn't_ be updated? One difference in behavior between my answer and @choroba's is that he's filtering for names starting with a specific prefix, whereas I assume that all servers with names are fair game.

Comment: No there is no other <server> element other than the one's I mentioned above in the xml file

Comment: Good deal, then; I expect you should have two working answers at this point (apologies about mine being initially broken).

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Both the solutions worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use proper XML tools for processing XML. For example, [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML::XSH2):

```
open file.xml ;
for //server {
    my $x = xsh:match(@name, '^(srv-usr--crt-Internal.vcdn--lfagent)([0-9]+)$') ;
    if (2 = count($x))
        set @name concat($x[1], 2+$x[2]) ;
}
save :b ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer uses [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sf.net/) for parsing and updating XML safely.

The first job is extracting the content:

```
filename="input.xml"
IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a old_names \
  < <(xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//server/@name' -v . -n <"$filename")
```

Next, generating the new values. Assuming that the only numbers that exist in any name are at the end:

```
new_names=( )
for name in "${old_names[@]}"; do
  name_prefix=${name%%[0-9]*}
  old_number=${name#$name_prefix}
  new_number=$(( old_number + ${#old_names[@]} ))
  new_names+=( "${name_prefix}${new_number}" )
done
```

Finally, generating and running a command to update the XML file:

```
update_command=( xmlstarlet ed )
for idx in ${!new_names[@]}; do
  update_command+=(
    -u "//server[$((idx + 1))]/@name" # XPath uses 1-indexed values
    -v "${new_names[$idx]}"           # ...whereas bash arrays are 0-indexed
  )
done
tempfile=$(mktemp "$filename.XXXXXX")
"${update_command[@]}" <"$filename" >"$tempfile" && mv "$tempfile" "$filename"
```

Comment: This has actually been tested end-to-end now. Apologies about the buggy first iteration.